# Notion of "current value" independent of subscribers

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

How can I construct an observable that just "keeps going"
independent of any subscribers (i.e. `refCount` etc. are out of the
question) and provides late subscribers with the most recent value?

Here is what I have tried:

```
// Approach 1
const myObservable$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).publish();
myObservable.connect();
myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
setTimeOut(function () {
  myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log("late", x));
}, 3500);

// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// late 4
// 4
// late 5
// ...
```

The problem with Approach 1 is that the late subscriber at t=3.5s
does not get the "current value" 3.
What I would like is an output of

```
// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// late 3
// 4
// late 4
// ...
```

Another approach uses `publishValue`:

```
// Approach 2
const myObservable$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).publishValue();
myObservable.connect();
myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
setTimeOut(function () {
  myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log("late", x));
}, 3500);

// undefined
// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// late 3
// 4
// late 4
// ...
```

In Approach 2, the late subscriber gets the "correct" value at t = 3.5s.
The problem with this approach is that we need to provide an initial
value which we might not always have.

```
// Approach 3
const myObservable$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).replay(1);
myObservable.connect();
myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
setTimeOut(function () {
  myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log("late", x));
}, 3500);

// 0
// 1
// 2
// 3
// late 0
// late 1
// late 2
// late 3
// 4
// late 4
// ...
```

At this point I am lost. I had the impression that `.replay(1)`
might solve my problem but somehow it does replay more than one event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approach 3 is the correct answer to your problem. However, you are using the [interface incorrectly](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/replay.md).

```
  /**
   *
   * @example
   * var res = source.replay(null, 3);
   * var res = source.replay(null, 3, 500);
   * var res = source.replay(null, 3, 500, scheduler);
   * var res = source.replay(function (x) { return x.take(6).repeat(); }, 3, 500, scheduler);
   *
   * @param selector [Optional] Selector function which can use the multicasted source sequence as many times as needed, without causing multiple subscriptions to the source sequence. Subscribers to the given source will receive all the notifications of the source subject to the specified replay buffer trimming policy.
   * @param bufferSize [Optional] Maximum element count of the replay buffer.
   * @param windowSize [Optional] Maximum time length of the replay buffer.
   * @param scheduler [Optional] Scheduler where connected observers within the selector function will be invoked on.
   * @returns {Observable} An observable sequence that contains the elements of a sequence produced by multicasting the source sequence within a selector function.
   */
Rx.Observable.prototype.replay([selector], [bufferSize], [window], [scheduler])
```

You will want to use the first overload `source.replay(null, 3)` so your code should be:

```
const myObservable$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).replay(null, 1);
myObservable$.connect();
myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
setTimeout(function () {
  myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log("late", x));
}, 3500);
```

Comment: Oops...:) Thanks for pointing this out! To my defense: the interface of `replay` seems to be different across the various Rx implementations (e.g. [RxJava](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#replay(int) )).

Answer (score 0):

Just `shareReplay` it!

```
const myObservable$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).shareReplay(1);
myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
setTimeout(function () {
  myObservable$.subscribe(x => console.log("late", x));
}, 3500);
```

Comment: `shareReplay` will not work. It calls `refCount` under the hood and will thus disconnect when there are no observers.

Comment: Sure, I got it know. Your requirement is to make it independent from ANY subscibers.